# Odoo 12. How to get link from binary field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

How to get a link to a file name? I get the text :(

```
class UploadFile(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'upload.file'

    product_attribute_value_id = fields.Many2one('product.at[![enter image description here][1]][1]tribute.value', string='Attribute Value',
                                             required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True)
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product', required=True)
    file = fields.Binary(string="Upload file")
    file_name = fields.Char("File Name")

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('product_attribute_value_id', 'product_id')
    def onchange_data_product(self):
        if not self.product_attribute_value_id or not self.product_id:
            return

        r = open('D:\picture\pdff.pdf', "rb").read()
        # base64.b64encode(r).decode('utf-8')
        self.file = base64.b64encode(r)
```

```
<record id="upload_file_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">upload.file.wizard</field>
    <field name="model">upload.file</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Upload attributes file">
            <group>
                <field name="product_id" string="Product"/>
                <field name="product_attribute_value_id"/>
                <field name="file" widget="binary" filename="file_name" string="Binary"/>
                <field name="file_name" invisible="1"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="save_file" string="Save" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

It is wizard form. When user change two field product_attribute_value_id and product_id 
I want to see a link to pdf.

Comment: For that field "file" should be readonly on wizard.

Comment: Chavada Viki file = fields.Binary(string="Upload file", readonly=True)  After that I see an empty line

Comment: Do it readonly from the wiew side not from backend. and also add one more attriibute to that binary field in view is force_save="1"

Comment: Chavada Viki I added <field name="file" widget="binary" readonly="1" force_save="1" filename="file_name" string="Binary"/> but line still empty :(( Field "file" get data such as: b'%PDF-1.6\n1 0 obj\n<</Type /Catalog\n/Pages .................

Comment: Hello, Senarist01 Please check your path is add correct with you get the read of 'D:\picture\pdff.pdf' this PDF data. Did u get?

Comment: Dipen Shah. The path is correct. (... and PDF too)